# TypeError: filter() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to filter the rows that have an specific date on a dataframe. they are in the form of month and day but I keep getting different errors. Not sure what is happening of how to solve it.

This is how my table looks like

[image]

And this is how I am trying to filter the `Date_Created` rows for `Jan 21`:

```py
df4 = df3.select("*").filter(Date_Created = 'Jan 21')
```

I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-a4124a5c0058> in <module>()
----> 1 df4 = df3.select("*").filter(Date_Created = 'Jan 21')

TypeError: filter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Date_Created'
```

I tried also changing to double quotes and using '' in the name of the column but nothing is working... I am kind of guessing right now...

Comment: use df4 =  df3.filter(F.col("Date_Created") == 'Jan 21') 
and you also need import pyspark.sql.functions as F

Comment: Other solution is to provide a proper python string to the filter method, i.e. ```"Date_Created = 'Jan 21'"```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `df.filter(df["Date_Created"] == "Jan 21")`

Here's an example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("Test").getOrCreate()
    df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [
            (1, "Jan 21", 566),
            (2, "Nov 22", 234),
            (3, "Dec 1", 123),
            (4, "Jan 21", 5466),
            (5, "Jan 21", 4566),
            (3, "Dec 4", 123),
            (3, "Dec 2", 123),
        ],
        ["id", "Date_Created", "Number"],
    )
    df = df.filter(df["Date_Created"] == "Jan 21")
```

Result:

```
+---+------------+------+
| id|Date_Created|Number|
+---+------------+------+
|  1|      Jan 21|   566|
|  4|      Jan 21|  5466|
|  5|      Jan 21|  4566|
+---+------------+------+
```